# Read remote PNG to output

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this currently running but cannot get it to output the image. It currently runs, but it doesn't output the image in the browser. Is it something to do with the encoding?

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var options = {
    host: 'www.website.com',
    path: '/'+req.url
  };

  http.request(options, function(response) {
   var str = '';

   response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
   });

   response.on('end', function () {
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png;'});
     res.end(str);
   });
  }).end();
}).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with that as a string, not a buffer -- so it'll mangle any data that doesn't fit into UTF-8. Which in an image is a lot.

You probably just want to connect the two streams:

`res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
response.pipe(res);`